# Swift leave out .self to invoke a function which needs metatype?

Tags: swift

Here is the code I write:

```
func printType<T: Any>(one: T.Type) {
    print(one)
}
func printType2<T: Any>(one: T.Type, name: String) {
    print(one)
}
printType(Set<Int>)
printType2(Set<Int>.self, name: "name")
```

I wonder why `printType(Set<Int>)` can work. And in `printType2(Set<Int>.self, name: "name")`, I can not leave out .self to make it work.

**Edit:**

I want to know which rule imply when I can omit `.self`. I had tried to find it in Apple official references, but failed.

**Edit:**

I test the codes in Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b).

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to say here besides "that's how the language currently works". If it's the only argument, you can omit `.self`.

Comment: This is like asking why an American football field is 100 yards long. It's because that's how football works.

Comment: @jtbandes But I think it should not omit .self, It just don't make sense in swift and I have not found any rule can explain it(in reference).

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ask it in apple official forum, and get an answer there:

> This is a famous undocumented feature of Swift, since 1.0 (or former > betas, which I cannot confirm).
>
> When calling a method or function with single type argument, you can omit > .self .
>   I guess this feature is included into Swift to make sizeof-like functions > neat, but not sure.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24980

Comment: but I still look forward to more official reference.