# Swift Metatyping Inconsistency

Tags: ios, swift, introspection, metatype

Given the following code...

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
enum MyEnum: MyProtocol {}
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {}
class MyClass: MyProtocol {}
func MyFunction(parameter: MyProtocol.Type) -> String {
    return "Hi"
}
```

Why do i have to use `.self` when assigning a variable...

```
var variable: MyProtocol.Type = MyStruct.self
```

and not when I am passing a metatype as a function parameter?

```
var result = MyFunction(MyStruct)
```

Comment: Probably a compiler bug. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33447419/77567).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like either a compiler bug. Personally I feel like `.self` should be included in the function argument.

However, once Swift's source code is released later this year there might be a better explanation. In the mean time you could file a radar.

EDIT: It appears to drop the `.self` requirement if the `Class.Type` is the only function parameter. [Swift leave out .self to invoke a function which needs metatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447419/swift-leave-out-self-to-invoke-a-function-which-needs-metatype)